# divs not aligning to top of parents

Tags: html, css

My divs aren't aligning with the top of their parents. I thought that is supposed to happen naturally without any extra css commands.

Here's an example of what's happening. I gave all the divs borders so you can see they are centering and not aligning to the top. I also have the masonry plugin on this, if that info helps.

[example](http://advancedplaylabs.com/test.php)

**Update:**

Changing all the margins and padding to 0 worked. It wasn't working before, i don't know why, maybe wasn't properly saving. Here's a self contained page with changes. The `p` tag is still lower down but I think that's normal for a `p` tag.

here is a single contained page: http://advancedplaylabs.com/div_top_align.html

here's the div

```
 <div class="main-container">
        <div class="main wrapper cleafix">
            
            <div id="content" class="container clearfix">
            
            <div class="item">
                <p style="border: 1px dashed green;">text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here.text here. </p></div>
                
                                 </div>               
              
            </div>
  </div>
```

and heres the css

```
.main-container {
        position: relative; 
        top:0px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px:
             border: 1px dashed red;
    }

    .main {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px:
    }

    #content {
        /*width: 980px;*/
        /*width: 95%;*/
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 0px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .item {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 0 0px 0;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 1px solid aqua;
    }
```

Comment: Check the padding and margins on the divs - you may need to force them to zero (padding:0;margin:0;).

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: thanks, i will update with code. I usually do, I just was so overwhelmed i wan't sure where to isolate it from. but I'm gonna look back and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to make sure your divs align with the top of their parent, I suggest you simply inspect the divs themselves to look for possible position or padding that is unintentionally/intentionally occurring within your divs.

Note how your class 'item' div is positioned absolutely within the id 'content' div and has the top property set to 30px... which will push it down 30 px.

There is a lot of this going on. Your content class also has padding top of 30px, your main wrapper class has padding top 5px...

I can go on but I think you can clearly follow me here: It is not happen naturally, it is intentional and it exists in your main.css file. If it is not intentional then it is being imported and you need to overwrite your divs to have the proper styling, or modify the main.css class manually.

Please review and let me know if you have more doubts about that.

Edit:

Let's be specific with the issues that I noticed and their fixes, according to your desire to align your divs to the top of their parents:

```
.main, #content { padding-top: 0; }
p { margin-top: 0; }
```

Note that I removed margin-top from p in order to align all the elements I saw to the top of their parents.

If you want to you can use child selectors for all the divs under a specific element:

```
.main-container div { padding-top: 0; margin-top: 0; }
```

Comment: I don't think this is it. even removing all of those and replacing them with 0px doesn't change anything. still trying to post the self contained code

Comment: actually this did work... i don't know what happened it wasn't changing anything before so I thought it was something else I overlooked. thanks. sorry I feel like this was kind of a waste of a post.

Comment: I also edited my answer in order to give you a more specific detail, glad that it worked :) be sure to accept / vote up the answer that was most helpful to you